# Drupal statistics does not count visits when I see the node from a custom panel

Tags: panels, nodes

I have a web site where each node has three diferents designs (i do it through panels and arguments) and i use the statistics module, that way i can see how many visits has the node.

But the statistics module jus count the visits when they visit the main design. I can explain with a example:

- website .com/node/01 <---when a user visit this url, a visit is counted
- website .com/node/01/mobile <----- here is not counted the visit
- website .com/node/01/lightbox <----here is not counted the visit

This was built for panels and arguments... so, is there anyway to put a php code in two panels that visitors don't have to start to count?

Best,

Comment: If I am not mistaken there is a setting in the Statistics module to do the updates via AJAX. There is also a js file in that module that does an call to statistics.php directly (bypassing index.php). You need to include js that does that call to statistics.php sending the nid as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

It's because panels doesn't invoke node_view(). Please try following code:

```
function MODULE_ctools_render_alter(&$info, &$page, &$context) {
  if ($context['handler']->task == 'node_view') {
    $key = $context['handler']->conf['context'];
    $node = $context['contexts'][$key]->data;
    statistics_node_view($node, 'full')
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears to me, the statistics_node_view() function is not incrementing. I saw db_merge() code in statistics_exit() though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using theme template preprocess function ie:

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

 $statistics = '(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: "'.url(drupal_get_path('module', 'statistics') . '/statistics.php').'",
      data: "nid='.arg(1).'"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);';
   drupal_add_js($statistics, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the db_merge() code from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21statistics%21statistics.module/function/statistics_exit/7.x

That is

```
db_merge('node_counter')->key(array('nid' => arg(1)))->fields(array(
        'daycount'   => 1,
        'totalcount' => 1,
        'timestamp'  => REQUEST_TIME,
      ))->expression('daycount', 'daycount + 1')->expression('totalcount',     'totalcount + 1')->execute();
```

... inside my own _ctools_render_alter() hook function. Hence, incrementing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Drupal 8.

```
function MODULE_panels_build_alter(array &$build, $panels_display) {
        if ($nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node')) {
                $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'statistics/drupal.statistics';
                $settings = ['data' => ['nid' => $nid], 'url' => \Drupal::request()->getBasePath() . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'statistics') . '/statistics.php'];
                $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['statistics'] = $settings;
        }   
}
```